# CUIXファイルの自動ロード

Tags: ijcad

インストーラで自作のCUIXファイルを
IJCAD起動時に自動で読み込みを行うように設定したいのですが、
方法がわかりません。
教えていただけないでしょうか。

環境は
IJCAD Mechanical 2022
です。

Comment: メインカスタマイズファイルを自動読み込みさせるのはどうでしょうか？
メインカスタマイズファイルへのアクセス権を特定のユーザーに限定すれば、管理者のみが修正可能で、共有カスタマイズファイルのように運用できるかもしれません。

※メインカスタマイズファイルは、以下のプロパティから設定できます。
GrxCAD.Interop.GcadPreferences.Files.MenuFileプロパティ

参考：
https://knowledge.autodesk.com/ja/support/autocad-lt/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/JPN/AutoCAD-LT/files/GUID-B3F0CB28-99D6-48B5-99C7-3E58249BB18C-htm.html

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。
説明不足で申し訳ございません。
メインカスタマイズファイルは既存のものを使いたいと思っており、
自作のCUIXファイルは部分カスタマイズファイルとして使用したいと考えております。自動で自作のCUIXファイルを部分カスタマイズファイルとしてロードする方法を知っていましたら教えていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: .NET APIであれば「Application.LoadPartialMenu(string filename) 」メソッドで部分カスタマイズファイルをロードすることが可能です。コマンドであれば、システム変数FILEDIA=0に設定したあと、「CUILOAD」コマンドを実行して部分カスタマイズファイルをロードすることができます。（※アンロードをしたい場合はLOADの前にUNをつける）このAPIで目的の動作を実現することはできますか？

Comment: 返答ありがとうございます。上記の方法でできそうです。教えていただきありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET APIであれば「Application.LoadPartialMenu(string filename) 」メソッドで部分カスタマイズファイルをロードすることが可能です。
（※アンロードをしたい場合はApplication.UnloadPartialMenu(string filename) メソッド）

コマンドであれば、システム変数FILEDIA=0に設定したあと、「CUILOAD」コマンドを実行して部分カスタマイズファイルをロードすることができます。
（※アンロードをしたい場合はCUIUNLOADコマンド）